# Weird conditional statement (same result)

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

Going through some code, I found this :

```
#ifdef trunc
# undef trunc
#endif
inline float trunc(float x)
{
    return (x < 0.0f) ? float(int(x)) : float(int(x));
}
inline double trunc(double x)
{
    return (x < 0.0f) ? double(int(x)) : double(int(x));
}
inline long double trunc(long double x)
{
    return (x < 0.0f) ? (long double)(int(x)) : (long double)(int(x));
}
#endif // _WIN32
```

Of course, the ?: operator always returns one and the same value in each case, regardless of its conditional expression.
On the other hand, I guess the author had his reasons to write these functions this way; I can't find one though. Any idea ? Is this just an error (typo) ?

**[EDIT] Reply from the author :**

Good point - this is just overzealous cut-and-paste from the definition of
round().  The following should be just fine (other than the limitation on the
range of int):

```
inline float trunc(float x)
{
    return float(int(x));
}
inline double trunc(double x)
{
    return double(int(x));
}
inline long double trunc(long double x)
{
    return (long double)(int(x));
}
```

Comment: No, the check doesn’t seem necessary, because casting to `int` truncates; it doesn’t round down. Might be remnants of somebody who thought otherwise. (Well, this being C++, this will probably turn out to be some horrible low-level optimization, won’t it?)

Comment: Could it be trying to force an exception in the case of NaNs, denormals and the like through the comparison, but return a reasonable result for "regular" numbers? If so, I would think there would be better ways to do it, but...

Comment: @twalberg:  If you were trying to handle NaNs (say, by forcing them to 0), you'd want to write `isnan(x) ? 0 : float(int(x))`, or, lacking the `isnan` macro, `x != x ? 0 : float(int(x))`.

Comment: You know what folks, I will just send an email to the author and clear this out. There is some fix to be made for sure, just have to figure out what exactly.

Comment: @JoeZ That would make sense, but, well... `#ifdef _WIN32`...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the generated assembly language look like with optimizations on?  I think the compiler would optimize these functions.

Comment: Just bad code, no.  If `abs(x)` is too big to fit into a long, undefined behavior occurs.  (Not to mention that `trunc` is declared in `<cmath>` and `<math.h>`.)

Comment: @minitech Actually, the cast to `int` risks undefined behavior.  This is _not_ the way to round to zero.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Did you mean to reply to somebody else?

Comment: @JamesKanze:  I've run into systems that did not define `trunc`.  Granted, older systems, but they exist.  Good point, though, that the cast to an integral isn't guaranteed to give a reasonable result if the original floating point value isn't representable in that type (eg. out of range).  I've added a note to my answer below.

Comment: See author's reply above.

Comment: Minor point: OP's new `trunc()` never produces -0.0.  @Joe Z 2nd `trunc()` nicely produces -0.0 when x has a `-` sign and truncation results in 0,

Comment: @minitech The comment is general, since it really applies to the original code.  But you did suggest that it was acceptable.

Comment: @JoeZ Yes.  I don't think `trunc` was in C90 (in which case, it wouldn't have been in C++98).  But I can't imagine a compiler which didn't have it today, and if I had to work around the fact that it was missing, I _wouldn't_ call the function `trunc` (to avoid problems with compilers where it wasn't missing).

Comment: And while I'm at it: the easiest way to implement this is using `modf`.  (Alternatively, you can do bounds checking, and only go through an integral type when necessary.  Above a certain value, _all_ floating point are integers, so `trunc` becomes a no-op.)

Comment: @JamesKanze:  About the only way I'd consider naming my version `trunc` is if it were wrapped in a compatibility `#ifdef` that made my version defined if the host OS didn't also define it. The example does have an `#ifdef` around it, but it seems like it could be more tightly scoped.  (eg. `#ifdef NO_TRUNC`, and then a separate configuration file elsewhere sets up what the platform supports and doesn't support, for example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code looks wrong.

My guess is that they *meant* something more like this:

```
inline float trunc(float x)
{
    return (x < 0.0f) ? -float(int(-x)) : float(int(x));
}
```

But even that's dubious.  I believe int(x) always performs truncation, so even then the two branches of `?:` should yield the same result.

In case rounding mode *does* matter to the typecast (and after a moment's thought, I'm not sure it does), you may really want to use a function like `modf`, `modff` or `modfl` to break the number into integer and fractional portions, and discard the fractional portion.

For example:

```
inline float trunc(float x)
{
    float int_part;
    modf(x, &int_part);
    return int_part;
}
```

Edit:  One other observation.  The original code will fail for values that do not fit in an `int`.  Yet another strike against it.

Comment: Original OP solution never produces -0.0.  Your 1st trunc(float x): For -1.0 < x < 0.0 it returns -0.0 (- zero).  For x = 0.0 or x = -0.0, it returns 0.0 (+zero).  A subtle oddity.  Your 2nd trunc() nicely returns -0.0 on -1.0 < x < 0.0.  Also x = -0.0.

Comment: @chux:  Interesting observation!  Usually -0.0 isn't a terribly important value, although I suppose it can be in some cases.  

As I recall, the sign of 0 can only be detected two ways: `copysign`, or taking the reciprocal.  (In the latter case, you end up with +Inf or -Inf, accordingly.)  Or am I forgetting a way?

Edit:  It appears `printf()` is obliged to print zero's sign.

Comment: `signbit()` and `atan2(x = -1, y = +0 or -0)` goes to +pi or -pi.  maybe others

Comment: Ah, ok.  I somehow missed `signbit().`  Seems to be new with C99 and C++11.  Time to dye those grey hairs and marinate in the C99 math library.  ;-)  As far as `atan2()` goes, is that behavior guaranteed?  I know some DSP libraries play fast and loose with such boundary conditions.

Comment: Concur about fast & looseness of things.  C11 F.10.1.4  (F --> An implementation that defines _ _STDC_IEC_559_ _ shall conform to the specifications in this annex) atan2(±0, x) returns ±π for x < 0.

Answer (score 0):

The code returns the same output for both the conditions. This is just a redundancy and moreover, the `float(int(x))` doesn't make a point. Because `int(x)` converts the number to an integer, again converting it to float or double makes no difference but only the type of the variable returned.